# Is there a standard style for documentation in PHP?

Tags: php, documentation

I'm new to PHP development, and I'm wondering if the community has any guidelines for inline documentation of code using comments.  I'd love something like Python's [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), but I'd settle for a format used by a popular document extraction tool, or even the documentation standard of a popular product.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most widely used form of API documentation for PHP is [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) a.k.a. phpdoc. Quite a lot of IDEs are also able to extract information to improve auto-completion hints using phpDocumentor style API docs.

Answer (score 10):

The phpdoc (phpDocumentor) style is common. It uses [DocComments containing DocBlocks](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/getting-started/what-is-a-docblock.html).

```
<?php
/**
 * This is a DocBlock for a function.
 */
function associatedFunction()
{
}

<?php
/**
 * I belong to a file
 */

/**
 * I belong to a class
 */
class Def
{
}
```

Tags and annotations:

```
 <?php
 /**
  * A summary informing the user what the associated element does.
  *
  * A *description*, that can span multiple lines, to go _in-depth_ into the details of this element
  * and to provide some background information or textual references.
  *
  * @param string $myArgument With a *description* of this argument, these may also
  *    span multiple lines.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  function myFunction($myArgument)
  {
  }
```

[Source](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/getting-started/your-first-set-of-documentation.html#what-does-a-docblock-look-like)

Answer (score 8):

Use [phpdoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/) (very similar to javadoc)

Answer (score 6):

PHPdoc is the first thing that comes to mind, take a look at http://www.phpdoc.org/

Answer (score 3):

[PEAR](http://pear.php.net/) (PHP Extension and Application Repository) has [coding standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php) that includes a [sample file](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.sample.php) using phpDocumentor, as well as some other useful conventions.